# Google Sheets script to run a process in every tab within worksheet only functioning on first tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this and I'm not sure why the following script isn't working. The first portion is a macro that adds a new row and enters the current date in specific fields (this is working fine). The second portion is supposed to run the same process for every tab in the worksheet except the one titled "Candidates". When I run the process only the first tab is effected. What am I missing?

```
function enternewrow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('19:19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M20').activate();
}

function runalltabs(){
  var spreadsheet=spreadsheetapp.getactive();
  var allsheets=spreadsheet.getsheets();

  allsheets.foreach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.getSheetname()!== "Candidates")
      sheet.activate();
      enternewrow();
    }
  )}
```

Comment: About `The second portion is supposed to run the same process for every tab in the worksheet except the one titled "Candidates". When I run the process only the first tab is effected.`, when I saw your function of `runalltabs()`, I think that there are multiple misspellings. So I think that your showing script doesn't work. From this situation, I'm worried that you have miscopied your script. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: I fixed the missing capitalizations in the vars and it seems to have fixed the issue. My next objective was to have this run on all tabs without excluding any, and my very inelegant solution was to simply change 

if(sheet.getSheetname()!== "Candidates")

to

if(sheet.getSheetname()!== "")

It works LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function enternewrow() {
  const xshts = ['Candidates'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheet().filter(sh => !~xshts.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach((sh, i) => {
    sh.getRange("A19").setFormula('=TODAY()');
    sh.getRange("H19").setFormula('=TODAY()');
    sh.getRange("M19").setFormula('=TODAY()');
    sh.getRange("M20").setFormula('=TODAY()');
  })
}
```